# Install of Update for KB2862330 fails with error 800B0100

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update

I'm working on a Windows 7 Home Premium system (64-bit) with Service Pack 1 installed. Windows update is trying to install an update for KB2862330, but it's failing with error 800B0100.  What's the trick to get this installed?

Some search engine research indicates this a general fault with Windows Update.  I'm not sure what connection, if any, this problem has to the fix for KB2862330.  The last Windows Update invocation installed a few updates, the one for KB2862330 was the last one in the queue and the only one to generate an error.

I tried the [Windows Update Troubleshooter](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/open-the-windows-update-troubleshooter) on Windows Update and the Background Intelligent Transfer Service.  It identified a few problems for Windows Update.  It fixed some the first time through and others on subsequent invocations.

The [System Update Readiness Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20858) wouldn't install.  The only error message was a generic 'Could not be installed'.  There was nothing useful in C:\Windows\logs\CBS\CheckSUR.log, either:

```
=================================
Checking System Update Readiness.
Binary Version 6.1.7601.22471
Package Version 22.0
2013-12-29 00:40

Checking Windows Servicing Packages

Checking Package Manifests and Catalogs
```

Comment: Did the first result on Google for "800B0100" not help? http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/windows-update-error-800b0100#1TC=windows-7

Comment: So the System Update Readiness Tool didn't work?

Comment: *If the System Update Readiness Tool encounters problems while running, it records them in a file called CheckSUR.log, which is located in your Windows folder, under Logs\CBS\. On a default installation of Windows this will be C:\Windows\Logs\CBS.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple runs of the Windows Update Troubleshooter on Windows Update and the Background Intelligent Transfer Service got the system to the point where the update installed.

After the update installed, I tried installing the System Update Readiness tool again.  It took an hour or so, but succeeded.  Still nothing exciting in C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CheckSUR.log:

```
=================================
Checking System Update Readiness.
Binary Version 6.1.7601.22471
Package Version 22.0
2013-12-29 10:45

Checking Windows Servicing Packages

Checking Package Manifests and Catalogs

Checking Package Watchlist

Checking Component Watchlist

Checking Packages

Checking Component Store

Summary:
Seconds executed: 3302
 No errors detected
```

I suppose based on the difference between the two log files, it could be inferred that in the earlier SUR invocation, there was some sort of problem with the Manifests or Catalogs.  Assuming all the output was properly flushed to the logfile before the failure.